# ServiceStack AuthFeature Allow Email Address for UserName

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I would like to use an email address as the UserName.  I can "/register" with only Email and Password (UserName is Nullable in the AuthUser table), but cannot then "/authenticate" because UserName is NULL.  If I copy Email over to UserName in the AuthUser table, I can successfully "/authenticate".

The problem is that an email address has invalid characters according to the validation RegEx in the IsValidUsername method of the AuthFeatureExtensions class and so, you can't "/register" with UserName = email address.

I'm stuck on how to override that if possible?

Thanks,

Jay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack Authentication already naturally supports authenticating by Email. When you authenticate with a Username that contains a '@' the ServiceStack will check the Email field instead of the Username.

So don't copy anything over, when you register just leave the Email in the Email field and the Username blank and it will work.

Comment: Ok, that worked (I think that if I had looked closer when I got the 401-Not Authenticated, I may have see a comma in the email address where there should have been a dot).  Question though:  On a successful authentication, should LastLoginAttempt have a value?